# Pulsar Consumer process delay in network connection reset

Tags: apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

I have an issue in pulsar consumer
The subscription type is Key_Shared
The consumer consumed message, it has been disconnected from pulsar with network error and pod has been restarted and message has not been processed
Consumer didn't send neghther ack nor nack to the server
The new consumer started and consumed message after 90 minutes
The problem is that Why didn't consumer receive message again immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by setting ackTimeout in consumer.

By default, the acknowledge timeout is disabled and that means that messages delivered to a consumer will not be re-delivered unless the consumer crashes.
I've set some configs for acknowledge timeout to process message again

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/concepts-messaging/

In spring-pulsar, this configuration works:
spring.pulsar.reactive.consumer.ack-timeout

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#:~:text=spring.pulsar.reactive.consumer.ack%2Dtimeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#:%7E:text=spring.pulsar.reactive.consumer.ack%2Dtimeout)

Answer (score 0):

shahsavan, are you using Spring for Apache Pulsar? I noticed the post is tagged w/ `spring-pulsar`. If you are not, do you mind untagging? I don't know the answer to your question but you can also check out the Apache Pulsar Slack channel.

Comment: Yes, we use spring-pulsar

Comment: Nice work @saeed-shahsavan, you answered your own question! I love it when that happens. Thanks for circling back w/ the information.